# PowerShell Multiple Custom Headers for columns

Tags: powershell, multiple-columns

I have the following code block to output two columns of data, with the headers `Name:` and `Members Of:`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -Like "UAT*"' -Properties Name, MemberOf | 
Select-Object @{N="Name:";E = {Name}}, @{N="Members Of:"; E ={$_.MemberOf -replace '\w+=' -join ";    "}}
```

However when I run this, only the `Members of:` column, the `Name:` column is completely blank. How can I populate both columns with custom headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the property `Name` using the pipeline object `$_.Name`, not just `Name`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -Like "UAT*"' -Properties Name, MemberOf |     
Select-Object @{N="Name:";E = {$_.Name}}, @{N="Members Of:"; E ={$_.MemberOf -replace '\w+=' -join ";    "}}
```